# How can I make script which will add double quotes automatically

Tags: python

I have about 2000 emails and i want to add them to python code which itself is ready but the emails don't have double quotes around them and I don't really want to add them manually, so maybe there is some way to make a script that will add the double quotes and commas at the end for emails.

Emails are stored one per line in text file and i want them to look like this ('"email@email.com",')

Comment: I see you have flagged this as a JavaScript question - where does that come into the equation?

Comment: Secondly, do you mean `!`  or do you mean `"`  or even  `'`  ?

Comment: As @MikeBrockington pointed, your question is not JavaScript related so you should remove the tag. Also, your question is very unclear, why do you need exclamation marks at the end of your emails? What do you mean by "add them to python code"?

Comment: Can you use BASH? You said the emails should have exclamations marks *around* them, so both at the start and at the end? Also, how are the emails stored? One per line in a file?

Comment: i need these (") around emails and are stored in text file one per line and yes i can use BASH @TomaszKasperczyk

Comment: These `"` are called double quotes.

Comment: I am sorry @Silveris english is not my first language but thanks for clearing this out

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
emails_string = 'email 1, email2, email3' 
emails_list = emails_string.split(',')
for email in emails_list:
  print ( '"' + email.strip() + '"' )
```

gives:

"email 1"
"email2"
"email3"

Comment: but my emails look like this (email@email.com) and i need them to look like this ("email@email.com",). Do you know how to that?

Comment: ok I've edited above. However, I'm not sure what your intended outcome is. This will print the emails to screen, but perhaps you them in an array, or as a string?